# rewriting sql query to pl/sql in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an application in oracle apex and there is a section which is called search_result and it returns this sql query

```
select
  "TITLE" CARD_TITLE,
  "POSTER_PATH" CARD_TEXT,
  "PRODUCTION_COMPANY" CARD_SUBTEXT,
  apex_string.get_initials("TITLE") CARD_INITIALS,
  'https://www.imdb.com/title/'||IMDB_ID CARD_LINK,
  null CARD_MODIFIERS,
  null CARD_COLOR,
  null CARD_ICON,
  "GENRE",
  "COUNTRY",
  "PRODUCTION_COMPANY",
  "RUNTIME",
  "BUDGET",
  "VOTE_AVERAGE",
  "TITLE",
  "POSTER_PATH"
from  "MOVIES"
order by vote_average desc
```

But I need to rewrite this query with pl/sql function body and
I've created package with function

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PRINTS AS
FUNCTION MOVIES_LIST RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
FUNCTION ORDER_VOTE RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
END PRINTS;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PRINTS AS
FUNCTION ORDER_VOTE
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
is 
    r_movie sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
open r_movie for select
  "TITLE" CARD_TITLE,
  "POSTER_PATH" CARD_TEXT,
  "PRODUCTION_COMPANY" CARD_SUBTEXT,
  apex_string.get_initials("TITLE") CARD_INITIALS,
  null CARD_MODIFIERS,
  null CARD_COLOR,
  null CARD_ICON,
  "GENRE",
  "COUNTRY",
  "PRODUCTION_COMPANY",
  "RUNTIME",
  "BUDGET",
  "VOTE_AVERAGE",
  "TITLE",
  "POSTER_PATH"
from  "MOVIES"
order by vote_average desc;
return r_movie;
END ORDER_VOTE;
END PRINTS;
```

Then I've tried to return this cursor in **pl/sql returning sql query block**:

```
declare 
   movie_cur sys_refcursor;
   a_movie   movies%rowtype; 
begin

   movie_cur := PRINTS.ORDER_VOTE;            -- call the movie function

   loop
      fetch movie_cur into a_movie;
      exit when movie_cur%notfound; 
   end loop; 
   return a_movie;
end;
```

but it throws this error:
**ORA-06550: line 12, column 11: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type**

what I did wrong and how should I fix it.

My db and some screenshots:

```
Column Name Data Type   Nullable    Default Primary Key
ID  NUMBER  No  "WKSP_DBMSPROJECT1"."ISEQ$$_111377832".nextval  1
TITLE   VARCHAR2(255)   Yes -   -
GENRE   VARCHAR2(50)    Yes -   -
COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50)    Yes -   -
PRODUCTION_COMPANY  VARCHAR2(255)   Yes -   -
RUNTIME NUMBER  Yes -   -
RELEASE_DATE    DATE    Yes -   -
OVERVIEW    VARCHAR2(4000)  Yes -   -
TAGLINE VARCHAR2(255)   Yes -   -
BUDGET  NUMBER  Yes -   -
REVENUE NUMBER  Yes -   -
POPULARITY  NUMBER  Yes -   -
VOTE_AVERAGE    NUMBER  Yes -   -
VOTE_COUNT  NUMBER  Yes -   -
POSTER_PATH VARCHAR2(255)   Yes -   -
TMDB_ID NUMBER  Yes -   -
IMDB_ID VARCHAR2(50)    Yes -   -
```

[IMDB DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSkbM.png)

[page design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baqqq.png)

[page itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFRaz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct. However you have written it an an anonymous block, which unfortunately cannot return results. You need to convert either to a function that returns a [reference cursor](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets)  or a procedure with an out parameter of a reference cursor.

```
create or replace 
function movies_list
  return sys_refcursor 
is
    r_movies sys_refcursor;
begin
   open r_movies for 
        select * from movies;
    return r_movies;
end movies_list;
```

Since it would seem your current code processes a column list instead of a select *. In that case you can the select with the exact query you have.

Processing:

```
declare 
   movie_cur sys_refcursor;
   a_movie   movies%rowtype; 
begin
   dbms_output.enable; 
   movie_cur := movies_list;            -- call the movie function
   dbms_output.put_line("Movie List');      
   loop
      fetch movie_cur into a_movie;       
      exit when movie_cur%not_found; 
      dbms_output.put_line(a_movie.title); 
   end loop; 
end;
```

The function is compiled and stored in the database (a stored procedure). THE ref-cursor is the result set of the query - just as your Apex section does not return the query, by  the result set of the query.

---

How to use ref cursor fully. (Well mostly). In response to **wrong type** exception.  

This error is the result of your query returning different columns than defined in the table but then trying to fetch into a variable defined as  movies%rowtype; Now that definition creates a structure that exactly match the tables column definition. However, your query has at least 4 columns that are not part of the table definition and perhaps 3 others. The columns Title, Production_Company, and Poster_Path are each used twice in query. Even though aliased they still represent an additional column in the result set. There is the function call, and the null selections.  Further there seems additional columns in the table that are not in the query. This does not make the query bad, just that it cannot match the movies%rowtype declaration.   

Two solutions come to mind. Just "select * from movies" and fetch into the
movies%rowtype declaration and derive the additional columns after the table data is retrieved. The other is to set up an appropriate cursor definition in the package spec. Where it can be references externally to the package. The issue being that you need to basically repeat that query in the body when you actually open the reference cursor.  

Assuming that you actually need those columns and you have table columns you want to avoid selecting since you do not need them (I like that part), I put together a [full demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd9326fe343228df8b1cbb02936870ed). Since I do not have your table definition and I have absolutely no idea what the function *apex_string.get_initials* even is, I just made something up for them. But they seem reasonable, and you should problems replacing with the actual.

Comment: So i need to create separate function which will return this query in my db and then return it in this pl/sql function body, right?

Comment: Not Quite, I have updated the answer to show how it is used, But yes it involves a separate function?

Comment: Basically, I should create this function in my db with my own query that I used in sql query and then in `pl/sql function body returning SQL query` write this **processing** code?

Comment: and as I understand I should return instead of just printing this cursor in order to interact with html elements

Comment: Yes. The printing was just for demonstration purpose. Within the loop you can use any code action needed.

Comment: I cannot tell what is wrong with code I cannot see. You need to post the code giving the error, at least the definitions and the call. Please do this by updating the question not as a comment.

Comment: Question have been updated. Check out, please.

Answer (score 2):

When using the type `PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query`, you need to return your SQL statement as a string. So the source of your region should look something like this:

```sql
BEGIN
  return 'SELECT * FROM MOVIES';
END;
```

Using the select that you provided in your comments you will need to use two single quotes to represent a quote in your string that you are returning.

```sql
BEGIN
    RETURN 'SELECT "TITLE"                            CARD_TITLE,
         "POSTER_PATH"                                CARD_TEXT,
         "PRODUCTION_COMPANY"                         CARD_SUBTEXT,
         apex_string.get_initials ("TITLE")           CARD_INITIALS,
         ''https://www.imdb.com/title/'' || IMDB_ID   CARD_LINK,
         NULL                                         CARD_MODIFIERS,
         NULL                                         CARD_COLOR,
         NULL                                         CARD_ICON,
         "GENRE",
         "COUNTRY",
         "PRODUCTION_COMPANY",
         "RUNTIME",
         "BUDGET",
         "VOTE_AVERAGE",
         "TITLE",
         "POSTER_PATH"
    FROM "MOVIES"
ORDER BY vote_average DESC';
END;
```

Comment: I've tried to do so like this `BEGIN
return 'select
  "TITLE" CARD_TITLE,
  "POSTER_PATH" CARD_TEXT,
  "PRODUCTION_COMPANY" CARD_SUBTEXT,
  apex_string.get_initials("TITLE") CARD_INITIALS,
  'https://www.imdb.com/title/'||IMDB_ID CARD_LINK,
  null CARD_MODIFIERS,
  null CARD_COLOR,
  null CARD_ICON,
  "GENRE",
  "COUNTRY",
  "PRODUCTION_COMPANY",
  "RUNTIME",
  "BUDGET",
  "VOTE_AVERAGE",
  "TITLE",
  "POSTER_PATH"
from  "MOVIES"
order by vote_average desc';
END;`

Comment: but it throws this error **ORA-06550: line 7, column 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "HTTPS" when expecting one of the following: * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2 like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset**

Comment: The syntax for your select is incorrect. You need to have `''` instead of `'` around your string in your query. See the updated answer.